# Start reading a large file from a certain line in perl

Tags: perl

1. I have to match 2 patterns (pattern_1 and pattern_2)
2. Data to match for pattern_2 depends upon pattern_1 (pattern_2 uses some data extracted out of pattern_1)
3. pattern_2 always occurs after pattern_1
4. once done matching pattern_2 i need to move back to the place where pattern_1 was matched and start again

I have following code:

```
open(DATA_IN, "<$in_file") or die "Couldn't open file $in_file, $!";
open(DATA_OUT, ">$out_file") or die "Couldn't open file $out_file, $!";
while(<DATA_IN>){
    if($_ =~ /pattern_1/){
        #extract some data
        open(DATA_TEMP, "<$in_file") or die "Couldn't open file $in_file, $!";
        TEMP: while(<DATA_TEMP>){
            if($_ =~ /pattern_2/){
                my $i = 0;
                my $line;
                while ($i<4){
                    $line = <DATA_TEMP>;
                    $i++;
                }
                print $line; #print the data 4 lines after the matched pattern_2
                last TEMP;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine, but the issue is that it loads $in_file everytime for pattern_1 match from the start which takes a long time.
Can you suggest me a way to load $in_file only from pattern_1 onwards?

Comment: What about [seek](http://p3rl.org/seek)?

Comment: Read the file once.  When you find the first pattern, start writing data to a temp file.  Read the temp file next time.  Also, unrelated, use `my $file = open(...`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `seek()` and `tell()` methods to move around in the file.  Something like the following:

```
open(DATA_IN, "<$in_file") or die "Couldn't open file $in_file, $!";
open(DATA_OUT, ">$out_file") or die "Couldn't open file $out_file, $!";
while(<DATA_IN>){
    if($_ =~ /pattern_1/){
        # Save the current position
        my $saved_position = tell(DATA_IN);

        # extract some data
        TEMP: while(<DATA_IN>){
            if($_ =~ /pattern_2/){
                my $i = 0;
                my $line;
                while ($i<4){
                    $line = <DATA_IN>;
                    $i++;
                }
                print $line; #print the data 4 lines after the matched pattern_2
                last TEMP;
            }
        }

        # Restore the saved position
        seek(DATA_IN, saved_position, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: @sid Please mark this as an accepted answer.  This will help other users looking for this issue.